# How to make CSS color transition time correctly with transform perspective?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

So I have this cute little spinner made to signify when something is loading. The perspective changes and the background color are supposed to change at the same time. I am having trouble getting the Transform and Transition timings to line up so that you don't see the color change, it needs to be already changed when the square flips so that it is a smooth transition.

[Link to JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0tyo7zy/)

HTML

```
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

CSS

```
    .spinner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px); background-color: #00b16a; }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg); background-color: #f22613;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg); background-color: #aaabae; }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1. Transitions interpolate smoothly (well, according to the easing function) between keyframes.
2. If you do not specify an attribute at a keyframe, it will interpolate without interruption over that keyframe.

With those in mind, you can change the keyframes to apply your color change in the middle of your perspective change. In addition, you'll set *two* keyframes for the color change, very close to each other, to ensure the interpolation happens over a small time slice.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px); background-color: #00b16a; }
  24.9% {background-color: #00b16a;}
  25.0% {background-color: #f22613;}
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg); background-color: #f22613;}
  74.9% { background-color: #f22613; }
  75% { background-color: #aaabae; }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg); background-color: #aaabae; }
}
```

Now, you'll notice that since you have the animation on infinite repeat, that you still get a color transition when the animation loops from 100% to 0%. You'll have to either specify `animation-direction: alternate;` or adjust your keyframes so that 100% ends at a reasonable tweening point between 100% and 0%.

**[DEMO using `alternate`](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/mk2z8bd0/)**

Comment: So if I were to adjust them, would it be best to have the entire animation happen before 50%?

Comment: I don't know about "best", but that would be one way to do it: 0-50% takes you from start to end state; 50-100% from end to start state.